# Python requests result doesn't match the website because of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

I'm trying to scrape links of products from a webpage (url below). The page uses JavaScript. I tried different libraries, but the links don't show up in the results (the links have the format `*/product/*`, as you can see by hovering over product links when you open the below url).

```py
url = 'https://www.bcliquorstores.com/product-catalogue?categoryclass=coolers%20%26%20ciders&special=new%20product&sort=name.raw:asc&page=1'

headers = {
    'Host': 'www.bcliquorstores.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.7,fa;q=0.3',
}
```

Using `requests` Library:

```py
import requests
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Using `urllib` library

```py
import urllib.request
request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
response.read().decode()
```

Using `requests_html` library:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession, AsyncHTMLSession
asession = AsyncHTMLSession()
r = await asession.get(url, headers=headers)
await r.html.arender()
res = r.html.html
```

When I search for the string `/product/` in the results, it cannot be found, but it's visible from the inspect window.

I know about Selenium, but I want to use it only if there is no other way.

Comment: There is no other way than running javascript using selenium or another library

Comment: @Konrad For instance `requests_html` says it supports JavaScript loading, but it's not working in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such websites do not usually use any sort of protection from scraping because they need to present their product for as many customers as possible.

If a page is dynamic (like one in your question), it can receive data only via HTTP request or Websocket connection. It can easily be obtained.

Open web inspector (<kbd>F12</kbd>) in your browser and reload the `url` page in question. You can see that after the page is loaded the browser makes a request to other API endpoint (.../ajax/...). It can be seen in "Network" tab.

So you can make a very simple script to get use of that endpoint:

```py
import requests


def print_product_urls():
    resp = requests.get(
        'https://www.bcliquorstores.com/ajax/browse?special=new+product&'
        'categoryclass=coolers+&+ciders&sort=name.raw:asc&size=24&page=1',
        headers={
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
                          'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                          'Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        }
    )
    for product in resp.json()['hits']['hits']:
        print(f'https://www.bcliquorstores.com/product/{product["_id"]}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_product_urls()
```

---

> There is no other way than running javascript using selenium or another library

Hello